# как проверить наличие любого элемента списка в переменной

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, telegram, aiogram

Я пытаюсь сделать проверку того есть ли в сообщении боту элемент содержащийся в списке но при попытке это сделать выходит вот такая ошибка:

```
ERROR:asyncio:Task exception was never retrieved
future: <Task finished coro=<Dispatcher._process_polling_updates() done, defined at C:\Users\Mihail\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py:395> exception=TypeError("'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not list")>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Mihail\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py", line 403, in _process_polling_updates
    for responses in itertools.chain.from_iterable(await self.process_updates(updates, fast)):
  File "C:\Users\Mihail\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py", line 232, in process_updates
    return await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
  File "C:\Users\Mihail\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\handler.py", line 117, in notify
    response = await handler_obj.handler(*args, **partial_data)
  File "C:\Users\Mihail\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py", line 253, in process_update
    return await self.message_handlers.notify(update.message)
  File "C:\Users\Mihail\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\handler.py", line 117, in notify
    response = await handler_obj.handler(*args, **partial_data)
  File "C:\Users\Mihail\Desktop\Дэ\Bot\bot.py", line 18, in echo
    if login in mssg:
TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not list
```

Как это решить ?
Вот мой код:

```py
import config
import logging
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, executor, types

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)

bot = Bot(token=config.API_TOKEN)
dp = Dispatcher(bot)



login = ["аккаунт1", "аккаунт2", "аккаунт3", "аккаунт4"]


@dp.message_handler()
async def echo(message: types.Message):
    mssg = message.text
    if login in mssg:
        print("some text")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)
```

Comment: `if mssg in login:` ? ...

Comment: Вы проверяете в if содержится ли ВЕСЬ список логинов в тексте сообщения.
Вам надо сделать отдельную проверку о том, что хотя бы один элемент из списка присутствует в mssg

Comment: @OPTIMUSPRIME Этот вариант не подходит так как в mssg содержится не только элемент из списка
Примерное содержание mssg:

аккаунт1 присутствует на сервере

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if any(l in mssg for l in login):
```